# Printing a character from an int value with a loop with a desired number of numbers per line of output

Tags: java

I am having trouble with the following code:

```
//Program 6.12
public class Ex6_12 {
    public static void printChars(char ch1, char ch2, int numberPerLine) {
      for (int i = ch1; i>ch2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<=numberPerLine; j++) {
          System.out.printf("%c ", (char)(i));
        }
        System.out.println("");
      }
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) {
      printChars('1', 'Z', 10);
    }
}
```

The preceding code prints out nothing and I want it to print out a chosen character to a different chosen character at a chosen number of characters per line. Uncertain where I made the mistake.

For this input I want the output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 :
; < = > ? @ A B C D 
E F G H I J K L M N 
O P Q R S T U V W X 
Y
```

(It ranges from the first `char` passed, to less than the last one, with as many `char`'s in a line as `numberPerLine`)

Comment: Is `'1'` more than or less than `'Z'`? (Hint: You want `<` in the loop condition, not `>`)

Comment: it is acsii values in chars so it is less. i believe Z is 90 in acsii and 1 is 1.

Comment: It does not, it has a value of 49

Comment: The program returns 11 of the same values in many different tables. How do I fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Change `for (int i = ch1; i>ch2; i++)` to `for (int i = ch1; i<ch2; i++)`

Comment: I did that but it returned 11 of the same characters in many different lines. I do not know what may be causing this problem. Thank you!

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: The desired output is all of the characters between ch1 and ch2 to be listed in output with the numberPerLine amount of characters per line in the output with as many lines as needed untill all the characters are written. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two loops for this. Since you are using `i` in the inner loop, but never incrementing it, you get the same letter printed `numberPerLine` times. Just have a check to see if the modulus of `numberPerLine` is equal to `numberPerLine - 1` (If there have been `numberPerLine` elements printed):

```
public static void printChars(char ch1, char ch2, int numberPerLine) {
     for (char i = ch1; i<ch2; i++) {
         System.out.printf("%c ", i);
         if((i-ch1) % numberPerLine == numberPerLine-1) {
              System.out.println("");
         }
     }        
}
```

Which will give:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : 
; < = > ? @ A B C D 
E F G H I J K L M N 
O P Q R S T U V W X 
Y
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a logical error in the first `for` loop in your `printChars` method. The loop should check if `i is less than ch2` to be executed. The current one will be an infinite loop if you do proper arguments while calling the method.

So, I changed this `for` loop `for (int i = ch1; i>ch2; i++)` to `for (int i = ch1; i<ch2; i++)` and as you might have guessed, it works. And, if you want print including the last char, then you will need to check till equal like `for (int i = ch1; i<=ch2; i++)`

```
//Program 6.12
public class Ex6_12 {
    public static void printChars(char ch1, char ch2, int numberPerLine) {
        for (int i = ch1; i < ch2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= numberPerLine; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%c ", (char) (i));
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printChars('1', 'Z', 10);
    }
}
```

Printing including the last char:

```
//Program 6.12
public class Ex6_12 {
    public static void printChars(char ch1, char ch2, int numberPerLine) {
        for (int i = ch1; i <= ch2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= numberPerLine; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%c ", (char) (i));
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printChars('1', 'Z', 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much! But how would I get the characters to print one of each together in the amount of characters in a line as the numberPerLine int? Thank you!

Comment: `GBlodgett` has already pointed that out. You can use that trick in for: `if((i-ch1) % numberPerLine == numberPerLine-1) {
              System.out.println("");
         }`